# Oracle query/ stored procedure to return multiple resultsets

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am using oracle database. When I tried to fetch the data using a single select query, it returned a single table in the dataset. 
How to write a select query or procedure in oracle, where I can get a dataset with 2-3(multiple) tables?

Comment: Do u want to join 2-3 tables and get the data using a SELECT statement?

Comment: The tables may or may not be related. But just to reduce the number of database hits, I want to get multiple number of tables in a single hit.

Comment: What are your tables, and what have you tried?

Comment: When I tried executing a simple selecte query like ' select * from table1' ,I could get the following output :
DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbc);
DataTable dt= ds.Tables[0];

This way ,I get only a single table. But now I want to get result of multiple queries in single hit.Like, Select * from table1; select * from table2; 
So that I can get : 
DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbc);
DataTable dt1= ds.Tables[0];
DataTable dt2= ds.Tables[1];

Comment: here you will get solution ..http://niharstechnicalfunda.blogspot.in/#!/2013/06/how-to-return-resultset-from-stored.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what I did, it was quite simple :

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");
object[] results = new object[3];
DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("DATABASE.SELECT_JOB_HISTORY.GetJobHistoryByEmployeeId",results);            
DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understood you question you would like to reduce the round trips to your database.
This can be done by a stored procedure in the following way:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971506.aspx#msdnorsps_topic6

Package header:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SELECT_JOB_HISTORY AS
TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
PROCEDURE GetJobHistoryByEmployeeId
(
    p_employee_id IN NUMBER,
    cur_JobHistory OUT T_CURSOR
);
END SELECT_JOB_HISTORY;
```

Package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SELECT_JOB_HISTORY AS
PROCEDURE GetJobHistoryByEmployeeId
(
    p_employee_id IN NUMBER,
    cur_JobHistory OUT T_CURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_JobHistory FOR
    SELECT * FROM JOB_HISTORY
        WHERE employee_id = p_employee_id;

END GetJobHistoryByEmployeeId;
END SELECT_JOB_HISTORY;
```

Client:

```
// create connection
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=oracledb;
    User Id=UserID;Password=Password;");

// create the command for the stored procedure
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT_JOB_HISTORY.GetJobHistoryByEmployeeId";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// add the parameters for the stored procedure including the REF CURSOR
// to retrieve the result set
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_employee_id", OracleType.Number).Value = 101;
cmd.Parameters.Add("cur_JobHistory", OracleType.Cursor).Direction =
    ParameterDirection.Output;

// open the connection and create the DataReader
conn.Open();
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// output the results and close the connection.
while(dr.Read())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        Console.Write(dr[i].ToString() + ";");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
conn.Close();
```

If you have to join these tables you can also use a normal join and split the result on the client (imho this is the way how a lot of ORMs do it).